# mouseleave event does not work in absolute child element

Tags: jquery, position, absolute, mouseenter

I have menu list like

```
<ul class="systeMenus">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The first `ul` tag is opening from some other `onmouseover` event of the link in another frameset frame.

The 2 `ul` opens by CSS `display:block;position:absolute; left:175px;` to parent `li` just like one menu appears inside parent `li` tag and hides at `onmouseout` event on the same tag `li`.

How can I hide these both the ULs when `mouseenter` on body. As I tried `$('body').mouseenter` and `parent $('ul.systeMenus').mouseleave`. Since I am getting problem on both of the implementation.

Any help is appreciated.Kindly provide the solution.

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing what the problem is?

Comment: I'm guessing this is happening in IE... I've just come across the same thing - because the element is AP the mouseleave event is triggered when you hover over padding, margin or border space? That's happening in my case - I think it's because the AP element is not considered to be inside its parent in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the hover in jquery

Something like that :

```
$("ul").hover(function(){ //triggered on mouseEnter}, function(){ //triggered on MouseLeave});
```

I've got a problem in IE one time with mouseEnter and mouseLeave, the hover fixed it.

If it's not working post a fiddle.
But by now maybe you have fixed your problem.